# BackgroundWorker change label multithread VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm new with multithread and backgroundworker.
I'm tried to write a simple test based upon tutorials and forum threads, but it is not working how I expected.

I have a windows form appilcation with `Button1`, `Label1`, `BackgroundWorker1` controls.

I'd like to do that when I click on the button:

- Backgroundworker check continously if a variable `state` True or False
- First change label text to False (first time state = false)
- if `state` is set True in the main thread, change label text to True (`state` is set True when the "Sample process" (For Next) ends)

My code is:

```
Public state As Boolean
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.Print("Button1_Click ThreadID - " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    state = False

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    '--Sample process in the main thread
    For c = 0 To 10000
        Debug.Print(c)
    Next

    state = True

End Sub


Dim c As Integer
Public Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork


    setlabel(state.ToString)

    Do While state = False
        Debug.Print("BackgroundWorker1_DoWork ThreadID - " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & " - state: " & state)
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop

    setlabel(state.ToString)
End Sub

Public Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Debug.Print("BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted - State: " & state)

End Sub

Sub setlabel(text As String)
    Label1.Invoke(Sub()
                      Label1.Text = text
                  End Sub)
End Sub
```

My problem is that:

- Label's text doesn't change to False at the begining of
  `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork`
- in the `Do While` there is no `Debug.Print`

The output is:

> ```
> Button1_Click ThreadID - 9
> 0
> 1
> 2
> ...
> 9998
> 9999
> 10000
> BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted - State: True
> ```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tying up the UI thread with the `For` loop:

```
For c = 0 To 10000
    Debug.Print(c)
Next
```

You need to let the UI thread go idle for the call to `setlabel(state.ToString)`
 to actually update the UI.

So you need to have something like a timer (or even a second background worker) wait a period of time before setting `state = True`.

Comment: Thank you the comment but sorry for my noob question, where and how I have to put a second Backgroundworker?

Comment: Aaaa.. I figured out based upon your comment!

Comment: I created a second backgroundworker after the first.
Put the For Next to the second BackgroundWorker's DoWork.
Put the state = True to the second BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted.

And it works! :)

thank you